# ngcontroller dont render the data on html Page

Tags: angularjs

I am very novice learning Angular js . I am following a video tutorials and made the following example. This doesn't show any output. can annyone let me know what am I missing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>Directives with Databinding</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngcontrollereg">
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
        <br />
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name | uppercase}}-{{cust.city}}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                { name: 'John Does', city: 'Phoenix' },
                { name: 'Lake Oswere', city: 'Phoenix' },
                { name: 'Raman', city: 'Kanchira' },
                { name: 'Alvaro', city: 'Kanchira' }
            ];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the angular module and register the controller with the module:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="ngcontrollereg">
  <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <br />
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name | uppercase}}-{{cust.city}}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('ngcontrollereg', []);
    app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
      $scope.customers = [{
        name: 'John Does',
        city: 'Phoenix'
      }, {
        name: 'Lake Oswere',
        city: 'Phoenix'
      }, {
        name: 'Raman',
        city: 'Kanchira'
      }, {
        name: 'Alvaro',
        city: 'Kanchira'
      }];
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: ohh..that wasn't mentiooned in my tutorials. Thanks a lot for the help. And registering a module for the controller is always necessary?

Comment: yes, that's the way angular binds the controller name (i.e. 'SimpleController') to the controller code. When you use 'SimpleController' in the html ng-controller attribute, angular goes looking for a controller that was registered with the same name. The name of the function has nothing to do with it, in fact, you can you an anonymous function like I did.

Comment: `$scope` is used to bind controller to view right? so, how does registering a module differ from this?

Comment: Every angular app needs to have at least one module. that is the 'app' variable I use. Controllers are used to bind the model to the view, and indeed, they use the $scope object to do so. But angular needs to know which controller controls which part of the html. That's were ng-controller comes into play: it says 'this piece of html uses this controller'. You need to register your controller with the angular module so a) angular knows that it is a controller and can inject the $scope object, and b) angular can map the controller name to the one you use in the ng-controller attribute.

Comment: Just to be clear: you usually only create one module for an angular app (unless you're writing reusable libs or complex apps). You can register multiple controllers to the same module.

Comment: Ohh coool that's interesting to know thanks for such a clear comment to make understanding simple for beginners like me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107926/discussion-between-fikkatra-and-programmerzzz).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create it like this :

```
angular.module('ngcontrollereg',[]).controller('SimpleController' ,function_Controller)

    function function_Controller($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
            { name: 'John Does', city: 'Phoenix' },
            { name: 'Lake Oswere', city: 'Phoenix' },
            { name: 'Raman', city: 'Kanchira' },
            { name: 'Alvaro', city: 'Kanchira' }
        ];
    }
```